# I want to use GraphViz in Maven project, but it fails: "class path contains multiple SLF4J providers"

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, graphviz

I want to use grahpViz with Maven but got this exception:

```
`https://pastebin.com/uKpemQ2c
```

`
my pom.xml file:

```
`https://pastebin.com/hvCKSS2N
```

`

I tried to use official documentation and added dependencies to pom.xml but it doesn't work.

Comment: All relevant information must be included in the question itself, not linked on off-site resources like pastebin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove your all dependency goupid hava `org.slf4j` and `org.apache.logging.log4j`

logging part only add this two, no more.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.6</version>
</dependency>
```